# Page numbering - removing page number from first page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

How do you turn off page numbering from the first page in a LaTeX document?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the line after begin document, do the follows:

```
\begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
```

Do the title and author before this.

Then, on the actual first page, do:

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: This did help a lot, it has remove numbering view from main (title) page

Answer (score 17):

usually, the first page contains only a page number as its "headers".  thus to turn off the page number on the first page, somewhere on that page issue the command
`\thispagestyle{empty}`.

if this command is used on a non-first page, it will wipe out also any running heads that have been included. this can be useful for producing occasional entirely blank pages.

Comment: If the first page contains either a `\chapter` command or `\maketitle` with the `notitlepage` class option, one has to issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` *after* the respective command.