# Remove all page numbers from the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, page-numbering

I want to send the table of content of a document containing only section and subsection titles. Sections of the document are empty, therefore, page numbers do not make sense at this stage. I get a big column of useless page numbers on the right.

```
Title ............. 3
Title ............. 3
Title ............. 3
```

I do not want to remove a few page numbers from the TOC numbering as asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/removing-page-number-from-toc), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100075/removing-a-page-numeration-from-table-of-contents) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41555/best-way-to-remove-page-numbers-from-a-toc). But I want to remove all page numbers from the TOC. The table of content would look like this

```
Title ............. 
Title ............. 
Title .............
```

Or better, without the dots:

```
Title 
Title  
Title
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tocloft`. From its manual:

[image]
[image]

A sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}
 \cftpagenumbersoff{section}
 \cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}
 \cftpagenumbersoff{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

> Now wondering how to publish the TOC only, but that's probably for another question.

Let us say the name of your .tex file is myfile.tex with the following content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}   % for demo only
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Compile this 2-3 times. This will generate an auxiliary file named `myfile.toc`.

Now prepare anothe .tex file name `mytoc.toc`, say, with the following contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \input{myfile.toc} 
\end{document}
```

Compile this to get only the toc of myfile.tex.

Comment: Since I am a nice guy (sometimes ;-)) (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Today! They won't count anyway :)

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar, I added `\usepackage{tocloft}`, `\cftpagenumbersoff{part}`, `\cftpagenumbersoff{section}`, `\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}`, to the latex preamble. And I get the desired result. Now wondering how to publish the TOC only, but that's probably for another question.

Comment: @Paul4forest Please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

The entries for the `ToC` (and `LoF`, `LoT` etc.) are done with `\addcontentsline`, more precisely:

```
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}
```

If `\thepage` is removed from the `\contentsline` call, **all** page numbers will be dropped.

If the page numbers for particular structuring levels should be removed use `tocloft` and its `\cftpagenumbersoff{section}` command etc. (as Harish Kumar showed in his answer)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\addcontentsline}{\thepage}{}{}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar: I am at home ;-) School holidays

Comment: @HarishKumar: No children (yet)... and I will grab all TikZ and `tcolorbox` questions then :-P

Comment: And how to avoid the dotted lines as well? I'm asking, because it looks strange: lines without an end.

Comment: @KeksDose: The O.P. wanted to have them, see his post.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am courious myself !

Comment: @KeksDose: The easiest way (without another package) (untested!): `\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks, for your solution, in fact I am also happy without the dots. As in the solution provided by HarishKumar.

Comment: @Paul4forest: If I would have known this I would have omitted them -- your question wasn't very clear then

Comment: My apologies @ChristianHupfer you are very right, my question wasn't clear. I was mostly frustrated by these page numbers. And both of your answers were really quick and satisfying. I posted the question before lunchtime, hoping I might get an answer in the afternoon. But within minutes, I had two replies. It surprised me, I expressed my surprise to a colleague at the lunch break.